# Autofac - Instance Scope WCF

Tags: autofac

I'm using Autofac with WCF.  My service (ExportWebService) needs to take in a dependancy (ExportService).  I setup the ApplicationStart to do this:

```
builder.Register(c => new ExportWebService(c.Resolve<ExportService>()));
```

But when I do so I get the error:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'httpRequest' is visible from the scope
>   in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a
>   component registered as per-HTTP request is being reqested by a
>   SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the
>   DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
>   never from the container itself.

I've also tried:

```
builder.RegisterType<ExportWebService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

In my service I have:

```
public ExportService ExportService
{
  get;
  set;
}

public ExportWebService(ExportService exportService)
{
  ExportService = exportService;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac WCF support doesn't have `InstancePerRequest` semantics. [There is a detailed FAQ on troubleshooting per-request dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) that may be interesting, but the short version here would probably be to switch the registration of your `ExportService` to `SingleInstance` or `InstancePerDependency`.

Comment: I actually changed it to InstancePerLifetimeScope() based on the following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/autofac/vPrvd0RtOtM/MKuGueLmMpEJ and it now works.